# How to locate a particular exception in a Exception stack

Tags: c#, api, exception, logic

Let us assume that a particular Exception "`SomeException`" is part of the exception stack,

so let us assume `ex.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException` is of type "`SomeException`"

Is there any built-in API in C# which will try to locate a given exception type in exception stack?

Example:

```
SomeException someExp = exp.LocateExceptionInStack(typeof(SomeException));
```

Comment: I don't think there is, because probably you don't want to do that. Why would you like to handle exceptions in such a convoluted way?

Comment: I've needed to do this before, trying to find a particular kind of Oracle exception somewhere in a stack which had varying depths depending on the cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't believe there's any built in way of doing it. It's not hard to write though:

```
public static T LocateException<T>(Exception outer) where T : Exception
{
    while (outer != null)
    {
        T candidate = outer as T;
        if (candidate != null)
        {
            return candidate;
        }
        outer = outer.InnerException;
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you're using C# 3 you could make it an extension method (just make the parameter "this Exception outer") and it would be even nicer to use:

```
SomeException nested = originalException.Locate<SomeException>();
```

(Note the shortening of the name as well - adjust to your own taste :)

Answer (score 1):

It's just 4 lines of code:

```
    public static bool Contains<T>(Exception exception)
        where T : Exception
    {
        if(exception is T)
            return true;

        return 
            exception.InnerException != null && 
            LocateExceptionInStack<T>(exception.InnerException);
    }
```

Comment: If it's supposed to do recursion, you might want to determine whether to call it Contains or LocateExceptionInStack...